# Timeseries Analysis

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression

I have the weekly time series data from 2011 to 2014 with 6 variables (Gross_Revenue, Attendence, Enrollmentcount etc.) and its having seasonality. I want forecast the Gross_Revnue for 2015 1st 15 weeks by using timeseries model. Please suggest me for which I need to use for this data. Either multivariate model or any ARIMA model.

Comment: You could try just predicting revenue from its past or use other variables too. You don't provide enough information for us to guide you on what's best for your project (and indeed you). It's not even evident that ARIMA is the most appropriate time series model; there are many others!

Comment: If you feel your data is proprietary, then simply code it .

Answer (score 1):

From reading your question, I feel that you may need more background. This book is fabulous and it is so good I purchased it but you may read if for free.

**Forecasting: principles and practice**
https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/3

All the code is in R and you can follow the examples and in one day, you'll be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @nickcox says there are many times series models.  The family of forecasting models can be seen here http://www.autobox.com/cms/index.php/afs-university/intro-to-forecasting/doc_download/23-forcasting-family-tree where ARIMA models are a subset of Transfer Function Models (includes causal vbariables).  Some guidelines to developing a time series model  can be found here http://www.autobox.com/cms/index.php/blog/entry/build-or-make-your-own-arima-forecasting-model. If you have possible predictors then by all means you should be considering multivariate time series models : note that simple multivariate regression is a particular case of a Transfer Function. Finally I had a role to play with the development of AUTOBOX and you should investigate a number of software providers including the free ones.

Comment: I am not able to understand that what you had given the explanation.Could you please explain by taking the one example problem

Comment: Hi, I have the data from 2011 to 2014 that consisting of 6 variables(Total attended members,Newly enrolled members,Newly renewed members,Film starting week,Total Proximal Revenue). My project client have 300 theatres. He wants forecast the 2015 1st 15 weeks proximal revenue by every week wist by using the times series model in r.could you please suggest me do I need to use the multivariate time series analysis or Any other analysis please it is urgent to me

Comment: Post your data and I will use it to build/identify a model. It is possible that you do not have any predictors just 6 predictands. In that case one model would be independently identified for each of the 6 series. Alternatively if you only have 1 series to predict then one would have 1 model with 1 Y variable and 5 predictors (X's) .